# Form undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function

I am using the following function to display form error for individual fields.

```
  # Error Helper for Form
  def show_errors(object, field_name)
    if object.errors.messages[field_name][0].present?
      "<label class='error'>" + object.errors.messages[field_name][0] + "</label>" if object.errors.any?
    end
  end
```

I am calling this from the Application Helper class as follows.

```
<%= show_errors(@category, :name).html_safe %>
```

When there is no error i am getting the following error.

```
undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no error, your `if` block skips and `show_errors` returns nil.
You may want to add something like `else return ""` just before the `end` in your `show_error`. Or check for nil in your helper.

Comment: do i need the "if object.errors.any?" at the end of the line as well?

Comment: Or you can use `try` method like `<%= show_errors(@category, :name).try(:html_safe) %>`

Comment: thanks. am new to ruby. why do we have an "if object.errors.any?" at the end

Comment: The `object` is a model object and the line before `if object.errors.any?` will only be executed if there is any error associated with model object we are working with.

Comment: So your method will return the label string if there is any error associated with the object (the errors are actually active record validation errors), otherwise nil will be returned.

Comment: Should be something like this:
    def show_errors(object, field_name)  
        if object.errors.messages[field_name][0].present?  
          if object.errors.any?  
            "<label class='error'>" + object.errors.messages[field_name][0] + "</label>"  
          else  
            ""  
        else  
          ""  
        end  
      end

Comment: @ManojMonga thanks a lot. Is there a way i can add the html_safe into the function 'show_errors()' itself?

Comment: Try `"<label class='error'>" + object.errors.messages[field_name][0] + "</label>".html_safe if object.errors.any?` and remove the `html_safe` from the view. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Sorry, I could not figure out how to format the code in the comment properly.

Comment: @nochkin You can't format the code in comments :) all you can do is make the text bold, italic, underline or highlight etc but no indentation is available.

Answer (score 3):

or adding this will also do the trick.

```
<%= show_errors(@category, :name).to_s.html_safe %>
```